# unbound method <method> must be called with <class> instance as first argument

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I would like to provide default behaviour for a class as illustrated below.

```
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self, my_method=None):
        self.my_method = my_method or np.min

Test().my_method([1, 2, 3]) # >>> 1
```

The code works as expected. To keep all the default values together for easier code maintenance I wanted to change the code to

```
import numpy as np

class Test:
    default_method = np.min

    def __init__(self, my_method=None):
        self.my_method = my_method or Test.default_method

Test().my_method([1, 2, 3]) # >>> TypeError
```

but the call to `my_method` fails with the error message `unbound method amin() must be called with Test instance as first argument (got list instance instead)`. Oddly, the code works as expected if I use the builtin `min` rather than `np.min`, i.e. the following works as expected.

```
import numpy as np

class Test:
    default_method = min # no np.

    def __init__(self, my_method=None):
        self.my_method = my_method or Test.default_method

Test().my_method([1, 2, 3]) # >>> 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In Python2, you should use new style class declarations. These derive from `object` as in `class Test(object):`. I quite simply forget the semantics of old-style classes but think this could bear on your problem.

Comment: @msw, thanks for the hing. However, the problem persists for new-style classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function stored as an attribute on a class object is treated as a method by Python. On Python 2, that means it requires the first argument to be an instance of the class (which will be passed automatically if the attribute is requested via an instance). On Python 3, unbound methods no longer check their arguments in that way (so your code would work as written).

To work around the issue on Python 2, try wrapping the `default_method` value with `staticmethod`:

```
class Test(object):
    default_method = staticmethod(np.min)
    #...
```

This might not be a bad idea even on Python 3, since you'll also be able to use `self.default_method` rather than explicitly naming the class.

As for why the code worked with `min` but not `np.min`, that's because they are implemented differently. You can see that from their `type`s:

```
>>> type(min)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(np.min)
<class 'function'>
```

Regular functions (like `np.min`) act as descriptors when they're attributes of a class (thus getting the "binding" behavior that was causing your issue). Builtin functions like `min` don't support the descriptor protocol, so the issue doesn't come up.